# egrep between 2 ranges in same column csv

Tags: bash, grep

not sure how to iterate between 2 sets of data on the same column, so lets say i have a CSV file with all titanic passangers and i want to extract the people between 20 and 29 years old and from 40 to 49 years old, and people who spoke english AND other lenguage lets say french, since both data are in the same column is quite challenging.
egrep does not seem to have a AND only and or so im struggling to find how to do it

so what i was trying was something like (from a coma separated csv)
3rd columns is Age and 8th is lenguage

(despite that i know that it might be easier solutions with some sed/awk etc i need it for training porposes in egrep)

`egrep "^.*,.*,[2-0][0-9],.*,.*,[eng.*]" titanic-passengers.csv`

thanks in advance.

Comment: `[eng.*]` doesn't do what you think it does. You clearly know that `[]` is for character sets like `[0-9]`, why would you think the same thing is for looking for strings like `eng`?

Comment: `[2-0]` is backwards, it should be `[0-2]`. But I thought you only want `2` and `4`, so it should be `[24]`.

Comment: Suggest you to provide sample input with expected output

Comment: What is the separator between the languages ?

Comment: thanks @Barmar true! as matter of fact that wasn't working well but i did not pay attention thanks for the tips! ill modify now.

Comment: @Fravadona space... so you have ,english french italian,  or ,english polish, and so on

Answer (score 1):

You should use `[^,]*` to match a single column. `.*` will match across multiple columns.

To match 20-29 use `2[0-9]`; to match 40-49 use `4[0-9]`. You can then combine them with `[24][0-9]`.

You don't need to put `[]` around the language, that's for matching a single character that's any of the characters in the brackets.

```
grep -E '^[^,]*,[^,]*,[24][0-9],[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,eng' titanic-passengers.csv
```

Comment: Oh, we got almost the same one, but you're right with the number of columns^^ as I may be right for the language

Comment: I didn't notice that the question said that the language column had multiple languages.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this one?

```sh
grep -E '^[^,]*,[^,*],[24][0-9],[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*( english|english )[^,]*' titanic-passengers.csv
```

@Barmar explained well the other patterns so I'll explain the "language" part.

To be sure to match at least one more language than english, you need to force a space before **or** after the word `english`. The **OR** operator is expressed by `(pattern1|pattern2)`